# How exactly do I rig this glow stick? It's probably really simple but I'm new

Tags: modeling, rigging, 3d-view

Sup fellas, I am making a project in external software. And need an animatable rigged glow stick, so I modeled one.

[image: Here it is]

After realising that rigging is extremely difficult for me, I tried somethings out
as you can see below, I am attempting to make that middle small bone the root bone, and then put two outer bones on each side that I can animate, is this possible?

[image: Here it is]

and if so, could something be so kind to walk me through it?

EDIT: The animation I would like to perform on this model is someone grabbing it, and craking half of it like a glow stick. So half of it stays static in the person's hand, while the other half bends.

Comment: You need to tell what kind of animation you want to do, what your object is supposed to do? Is it rigid, does it bend, etc?

Comment: FIXED! My bad, I forgot about that haha.

Comment: If you just make a chain of 2 bones from the bottom to the top and weight it properly, wouldn't that be enough? Then the character grabs it from the first bone and bends it with the second bone.
How familiar are you with rigging? Maybe check out some basic rigging tutorials first, then you'll have the tools to rig this stick.

Comment: This is a good intro to rigging in Blender and probably enough for what you're trying to achieve:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IAiTYaiZmY0&t=490s&ab_channel=GrantAbbitt